# Creating columns in bootstrap

Tags: html, css

EDIT: I realized I was putting dots in front of classes. Please stop downvoting.

I'm trying to create columns in my search results. I want the results to appear in columns of 3.

This is my code:

```
    <div class=".container">
        <div class=".row">
            <div class=".col-xs-3">
            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>


            <?php 
                if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                    echo '<p>';
                    the_post_thumbnail("small");
                    echo '</p>';
                }
            ?>
            <p><br /><?php the_excerpt(); ?><p>

    </div>
        </div>
            </div>
```

Nothing happening.

Classes found at: http://tomasjanecek.cz/en/clanky/post/list-of-bootstrap-3-css-classes-with-description

Comment: I take it you didn't read up on CSS 101.

Comment: Quoted from that url *"Every web developer should know how to properly code a responsive website."*

Comment: Take this "." out of the class names. Correct is **<div class="container">** and **<div class="row">** and **<div class="col-xs-3">**.

Comment: Yeah I don't know why the dots are there.

But Fred, I should probably read HTML 101, not CSS 101. The CSS is fine, it's the HTML that's the problem lol.

Comment: Either way, HTML is HTML, CSS is CSS. Two different animals here ;-) @Paze

Answer (score 7, accepted):

CSS class selectors begin with a `.` character.

HTML class names do not (well, they can, but it is more trouble than it is worth and the Bootstrap CSS doesn't expect them to).

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
```

Comment: Now I can't delete the question. Lol I don't know why I put the dots there. Time to rest.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `.` character inside HTML tags classes

Try this code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
            <?php 
                if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                    echo '<p>';
                    the_post_thumbnail("small");
                    echo '</p>';
                }
            ?>
            <p><br /><?php the_excerpt(); ?><p>
       </div>
   </div>
```